# Force Chrome to open with specific command line switches

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

We've created a shortcut/lnk with the necessary switches, but this only works if the user clicks on that specific shortcut. Is it possible to force chrome.exe to always open with specific command line switches?

Or is there a group policy to set these launchparameters (looks like they used to have this, but have deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the options you can set via command line can also be set via group policy or through `chrome://about` or `chrome://flags`.

Group policy support is not deprecated. In fact, it has matured significantly over the years. Simply download and use the Chrome .ADMX, and be sure to keep it up to date as it is continually evolving with new Chrome versions. Almost anything specified on the command line should be able to be specified via group policy.

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwindows

Without specific knowledge of what options you’re trying to change, this is the best I can do.